# How to pass dynamic parameters from YAML to the header which appears in every page of word document?

Tags: r-markdown

I want to have a dynamic header to appear on every page of word document after knitting an r markdown file. The header includes the document title and ID that are the user inputs passed to r markdown via r shiny app.

I followed the link https://vimeo.com/110804387 to create header for word template Template.docx.  The header appears on every page but the parameters from YAML can't be passed to the header.

The header in the Template.docx:

```
    Document title: `r params$title`  
    Document ID: `r params$id`
```

The YAML in r markdown:

```
    output: 
      word_document:
        reference_docx:  Template.docx
    params:
      title:  title
      id:  id
```

The word template image:
[Image of the Template.docx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvfHB.png)

Do you know how I can get the parameters passed to the header?  I really appreciate your help.  I'm learning R and working on this first project at the same time.  I'm using RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

try adding quotes to `r `  --> "`r `"